# Python Code only gives first response

Tags: python

I have coded responses to users inputing their age, but it only returns the first response. Any ideas why?

```
print('Lets play a game with your age!')
int(input('Enter your age'))
if int() <= 10:
    print("You still need to wear what your Mom puts out for you!")
elif int() >= 11 and int() <= 15:
    print("Congratulations! You are old enough to chew gum and walk at the same time!")
elif int()  >= 16 and int() <= 18:
    print("You are old enough to sit in the emergency exit row of an airplane!")
elif int() >= 19 and int() <= 29:
    print("Wow! You are REALLY old!!!")
else:
    print("Your age is off the charts. Are you sure you're not a dinosaur?")
```

Then I did more research and tried this:

```
print('Lets play a game with your age!')
int(input('Enter your age'))
if int(input('Enter your age')) <= 10:
    print("You still need to wear what your Mom puts out for you!")
elif int(input('Enter your age')) >= 11 and int(input('Enter your age')) <= 15:
    print("Congratulations! You are old enough to chew gum and walk at the same time!")
elif int(input('Enter your age'))  >= 16 and int(input('Enter your age')) <= 18:
    print("You are old enough to sit in the emergency exit row of an airplane!")
elif int(input('Enter your age')) >= 19 and int(input('Enter your age')) <= 29:
    print("Wow! You are REALLY old!!!")
else:
    print("Your age is off the charts. Are you sure you're not a dinosaur?")
```

This works, but the problem is that depending on the variable entered, it will ask for an age input between 2 to 8 times (one for each int(input('Enter your age')).

I've been working on trying to solve this for over an hour and it's driving me mad! LOL

Comment: Serious question: do you have a reason for believing that `int()` returns the value of (or is in any way associated with) the preceding call to `input`?

Comment: Chepner, I know that int turns my string into a variable. It was how to make the conversion stick that was bugging me. It is so simple when someone points it out and I understand the logic behind it. But when you are not an experienced coder, sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees and vice versa :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assign the `input()` value to a variable,
 one time before all the `if` statements

```
print('Lets play a game with your age!')
age = int(input('Enter your age'))
if age <= 10:
    print("You still need to wear what your Mom puts out for you!")
elif age  >= 11 and age <= 15:
    print("Congratulations! You are old enough to chew gum and walk at the same time!")
elif age >= 16 and age <= 18:
    print("You are old enough to sit in the emergency exit row of an airplane!")
elif age >= 19 and age <= 29:
    print("Wow! You are REALLY old!!!")
else:
    print("Your age is off the charts. Are you sure you're not a dinosaur?")
```

Comment: It made perfect sense - I have since used the idea (but not with int :-) to create blank lists and populate them with input, etc. For some reason I just couldn't initially wrap my head around needing a container for the input. Thank you very much for helping me along on my Python coding journey :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign the value of input() to a variable.

```
age = int(input('Enter your age'))
if age < 10:
    print("less than 10")
```

Comment: Doh! Thank you all. That makes sense. I need a container for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for their input, but then aren't saving it anywhere.

Do

```
response = int(input('Enter your age'))
```

and then replace lines like `if int() <= 10` with `if response <= 10`, etc.

```
print('Lets play a game with your age!')
response = int(input('Enter your age')) # assign result of input to a variable
if response <= 10:
    print("You still need to wear what your Mom puts out for you!")
elif response >= 11 and response <= 15:
    print("Congratulations! You are old enough to chew gum and walk at the same time!")
elif response >= 16 and response <= 18:
    print("You are old enough to sit in the emergency exit row of an airplane!")
elif response >= 19 and response <= 29:
    print("Wow! You are REALLY old!!!")
else:
    print("Your age is off the charts. Are you sure you're not a dinosaur?")
```

---

Understand what you're doing. *Every time* you write `input()`, a brand new prompt is asked. This is because *every time* you do something like `foo(args)`, you are *invoking* (forcing Python to run) that function with arguments `args`.

`input()` is a function. It asks for a response *once* and gives you a value exactly once. Each time Python sees it, it *will* run it and get a completely new value.

If you only want the value *once*, then assign it to a new variable. That variable will remember the response as a value, and everytime you use it, it will evaluate to that value.

Comment: I saw that once I played with it and got 2 to 8 requests for input before it ran the correct response. LOL In my later coding that I did yesterday I use descriptive variable names to collect and store the input. Thanks for your help!